# VBA Run-time error 91 - Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'd be grateful for some guidance. I'm new to coding and this has got me really stumped.

I keep getting a Run-time error 91 with the following code, although it actually works as intended.

The error is at `Set wd = wb.Sheets("Sitel Audit")` although it accurately pulls from the active worksheet to the new one named Sitel Audit.

```
Private Sub Extract()


Dim FileYear As String
Dim FileMonth As String
Dim AgentName As String
Dim Agreement As String
Dim CallDate As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wd As Worksheet
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
Dim e As String
Dim f As String
Dim g As String
Dim h As String
Dim i As String
Dim j As String
Dim k As String
Dim l As String
Dim m As String
Dim n As String
Dim o As String
Dim p As String
Dim q As String
Dim r As String
Dim found As Range
Dim wtf As Range

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\matthew.varnham\Desktop\QA Improvements\SITEL - Inbound Tracker.xlsm")
Set wd = wb.Sheets("Sitel Audit")
Set wtf = Sheets("Observation Sheet").Range("E8")
Set found = wd.Columns("E:E").find(what:=wtf, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

Set wss = Sheets("Observation Sheet")
a = wss.Range("F17").Value '1
b = wss.Range("F20").Value '2
c = wss.Range("F21").Value '3
d = wss.Range("F22").Value '4
e = wss.Range("F23").Value '5
f = wss.Range("F26").Value '6
g = wss.Range("F27").Value '7
h = wss.Range("F28").Value '8
i = wss.Range("F30").Value '9
j = wss.Range("F31").Value '10
k = wss.Range("F34").Value '11
l = wss.Range("F35").Value '12
m = wss.Range("F36").Value '13
n = wss.Range("F37").Value '14
o = wss.Range("F40").Value '15
p = wss.Range("F41").Value '16
q = wss.Range("F44").Value '17
r = wss.Range("F47").Value '18



wd.Range("P" & found.Row).Value = a
wd.Range("Q" & found.Row).Value = b
wd.Range("R" & found.Row).Value = c
wd.Range("S" & found.Row).Value = d
wd.Range("T" & found.Row).Value = e
wd.Range("U" & found.Row).Value = f
wd.Range("Y" & found.Row).Value = g
wd.Range("Z" & found.Row).Value = h
wd.Range("AB" & found.Row).Value = i
wd.Range("AC" & found.Row).Value = j
wd.Range("AD" & found.Row).Value = k
wd.Range("AE" & found.Row).Value = l
wd.Range("AF" & found.Row).Value = m
wd.Range("AG" & found.Row).Value = n
wd.Range("AH" & found.Row).Value = o
wd.Range("AI" & found.Row).Value = p
wd.Range("AJ" & found.Row).Value = q
wd.Range("AK" & found.Row).Value = r

wb.Save
Workbooks(1).Close

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have cut your code down a lot for you by introducing a couple of arrays and by combining the DIMs to a couple of lines:

```
Private Sub Extract()

Dim CopyArray As Variant, PasteArray As Variant, X As Long, FileYear As String, FileMonth As String, AgentName As String, Agreement As String
Dim CallDate As String, wb As Workbook, wd As Worksheet, found As Range, wtf As Range

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\matthew.varnham\Desktop\QA Improvements\SITEL - Inbound Tracker.xlsm")
Set wd = wb.Sheets("Sitel Audit")
Set wtf = Sheets("Observation Sheet").Range("E8")
Set found = wd.Columns("E:E").Find(what:=wtf, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set wss = Sheets("Observation Sheet")
CopyArray = Array(17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 34, 35, 36, 37, 40, 41, 44, 47)
PasteArray = Array("P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "Y", "Z", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK")

For X = LBound(CopyArray) To UBound(CopyArray)
    wd.Range(PasteArray(X) & found.Row).Value = wss.Range("F" & CopyArray(X)).Value
Next

wb.Save
Workbooks(1).Close

End Sub
```

Test you have spelled the sheet correctly by opening the workbook manually and using the debug window (ctrl-g) and typeing (including the question mark) `?Sheets("Sitel Audit").name`

If that returns the name then we know everything should be okay so we can start looking at other possibilities.

If it errors then you have the sheet name wrong.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your help with this. Just tried the above in the debug window and i'm getting run-time error 9 - subscript out of range. Though the sheet name is correct. Not sure whether its relevant but its a worksheet in the destination workbook?

Comment: Is that the book that is active when you did that in the debug window? Try prefacing it like this `?Workbook("Observation Sheet").worksheets("Sitel Audit").name` If it still errors then there is a problem with the sheet name. If this is the case just copy the name from the tab into your code, it may be a random space at the end of the worksheet name

Comment: Yes, the workbook with (“Sitel Audit”) was active when I did that in the debug mode. Might be worth mentioning that (“Observation Sheet”) is the source sheet which hosts the macro and (“Sitel Audit”) is the destination sheet in the workbook that the Macro opens. (SITEL - Inbound Tracker.xlsm. Tried your suggestion and I’m now getting a compile error - sub or function not defined.

Comment: My Bad, try this in the debug window please: `?Workbook("SITEL - Inbound Tracker.xlsm").worksheets("Sitel Audit").name` (make sure the macro workbook is open of course)

Comment: Coming back the same, with a compile error. I copied worksheet name and changing the name to just Sitel and its still returns the same.

Comment: A compile error would indicate a problem with the code other than the sheet name. In the VBA window click the debug menu then `compile VBA project` It will highlight the line and tell you the problem.

Comment: It seems the 'compile VBA project' option on the debug menu is grayed out.

Comment: It's odd because the macro works just as I need it to,

Comment: Thanks again for your help Dan! As other than the run-time error appearing the macro does what it should I've added '''On Error Resume Next''', It obviously hasn't resolved the issue, but makes the macro work without disruption.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's not the best way forwards but sometimes you have to do it just to get it working.